# Converting flattened data from db to n-ary tree (PHP)

Tags: php

I am a new dev struggling with PHP.  My ticket is to create an export function that takes a db return of flattened data and create an n-ary tree structure from the data.

Here is my working proof of concept that is working correctly, but not working when I implement it to our code base.

**Data before:**
[data before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUHiw.png)
**Data after:**
[data after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qiiH.png)

**proof of concept code:**

```
<?php

function buildTree($list, $ParentID) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($list as $element) {
        if ($element['ParentID'] == $ParentID) {
            $children = buildTree($list, $element['ID']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['Children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
$tree = buildTree($list, $list[0]['ParentID']);
```

When I go to implement it in our code base I am struggling with getting the recursive method to properly return.  It seems to be failing at at the if ($children) statement. I have a suspicion it is due to the proof of concept adding a 'Children' key pair value to the arrays that is not being carried over to the code base implementation.  Example of code base code:

```
function buildTree($list, $ParentID) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach ($list as $element) {
        if ($element['ParentID'] == $ParentID) {
            $children = buildTree($list, $element['ID']);
                if ($children) {
                    $element['otherData'] = $children;
                }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

To reiterate, I believe I am failing at inserting the Children key value pair into each row of the array that is being returned from the db.  The proof of concept allows for the insertion of the 'Children' key value, but doesn't seem to be working when I implement it in our code base.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, ty!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. See live example: https://onlinephp.io/c/49748

Comment: Please post example data/code as _text_, not images. We cannot copy/paste code from an image.

Comment: Needs Debugging Details

Comment: Hi all, thank you for taking the time to go over this. I worked with a dev to install xdebug into vs code as I was trying to write the data to a file to debug. This helped me find that the code was working as intended, there was just an issue with how I was printing it to a file. In the future I will be sure to include examples as text. I appreciate your guys time, thank you!